# How to fetch local attribute value through QuerySpec in Windchill

Tags: ptc-windchill

I created a local string type attribute on a type in Windchill. I'm trying to fetch the value of that attribute using QuerySpec but it's throwing the following exception:

> 2019-04-16 20:53:05,092 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8011-exec-5]
>   wt.system.err - wt.query.QueryException: Attribute
>   "ptc_str_89typeInfoLCSProduct" is not a member of class "class
>   com.lcs.wc.product.LCSSKU" 2019-04-16 20:53:05,092 INFO
>   [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8011-exec-5] wt.system.err - Nested exception is:
>   Attribute "ptc_str_89typeInfoLCSProduct" is not a member of class
>   "class com.lcs.wc.produ

Following is my code:

```
    String colorwayId = product.getFlexType().getAttribute("colorwayID")
            .getColumnName();
    QuerySpec qs = new QuerySpec(); 
    int classIndex = qs.appendClassList(typeDefRef.getKey().getClass(), false); 
    ClassAttribute ca = new ClassAttribute(
            typeDefRef.getKey().getClass(), colorwayId);
    qs.appendSelect(ca, new int[] { classIndex }, false);
    QueryResult qr = PersistenceHelper.manager.find(qs);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `PersistableAdapter` api to retrieve attribute values?

Comment: I need to fetch the maximum value of the three columns.

Answer (score -1):

Normally ClassAttribute gets attribute name instead of column name (database column).
Your **ptc_str_89typeInfoLCSProduct** column is in fact **typeInfoLCSProduct.ptc_str_89** like **State** is **state.state**.

To get this information, you need to use PersistableAdapter like this:

```
public String getAttributeColumnName(String softType, String logicalAttributeName) throws WTException {
    PersistableAdapter persistableAdapter = new PersistableAdapter(softType, Locale.getDefault(), Operation.DISPLAY);
    persistableAdapter.load(logicalAttributeName);

    AttributeTypeSummary attributeDescriptor = persistableAdapter.getAttributeDescriptor(logicalAttributeName);

    return null != attributeDescriptor ? (String) attributeDescriptor.get(AttributeTypeSummary.DESCRIPTION) : null;
}
```

And then use this method:

```
String colorwayId = getAttributeColumnName("your_softtype", "attribute_name_from_type_manager");
```